# Understanding alignment concept

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

> An alignment is an implementation-defined integer value representing
>   the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given
>   object can be allocated.

That concept is a bit unclear. For instance:

```
struct B { long double d; };
struct D : virtual B { char c; }
```

> When D is the type of a complete object, it will have a subobject of
>   type B, so it must be aligned appropriately for a `long double`.

What does it mean? `sizeof(long double)` is the number of bytes between what in that case??

Comment: is alignment as a concept clear to you?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath No. It is hard to imagine. Could you get some example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most CPU's have "preferences" about where data can be stored. When reading or writing to a memory address, the operation may be slower (or completely illegal) if the address doesn't match the data size you try to write. For example, it is common to require that 4-byte integers be allocated starting on an address that is divisible by 4.

That is, an `int` stored on address `7` is either less efficient, or completely illegal, depending on your CPU. But if it is stored at address `8`, the CPU is happy.

That is what alignment expresses: for any object of type `T` what must its address be divisible by, in order to satisfy the CPU's requirements?"

In C++, the alignment for an object is left implementation-defined (because, as said above, it depends on the CPU architecture). C++ merely says that every object *has* an alignment, and describes how to determine the alignment of compound objects.

Being "aligned for a `long double`" simply means that the object must be allocated so that its first byte is placed in an address that is valid for a `long double`. If the CPU architecture specifies the alignment of a `long double` to be 10 (for example), then it means that every object with this alignment must be allocated on an address that is divisible by 10.

Comment: One implication is the concept of padding.  Example: "struct A {char c; long double d};".  The long double field will still have long double alignment-- which means there will be unused spaced between c and d.

Comment: But what if in some architecture sizeof(char) does not divide sizeof(long double)?

Comment: @St.Antario `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so that architecture doesn't exist.

Comment: @St.Antario  Also the size of the padding ("unused spaces") doesn't need to correspond to the size of any existing type.  It only needs to be enough so that the next field is properly aligned.  From my struct A example, assume that sizeof(long double)==10(odd figure, but this an example).  The padding would be 9 bytes (sizeof(long double)-sizeof(char)).

Comment: @St.Antario The C++ standard does place a few extra guarantees: An object's size is guaranteed to be a multiple of its alignment. (so a 8-byte `double` cannot have an alignment of 3) And `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1. It also guarantees that when allocating objects, whether with `new` or on the stack, they are placed on well-aligned addresses. For compound objects, this also means that the compiler may have to insert padding, to ensure that every member object gets aligned correctly, and to ensure that the complete object's size is a multiple of the most-aligned member.

Answer (score 1):

I completely understand your uncertainty.  That might be among the worst attempts I have seen to explain what alignment is.

Think of it in practical terms.

```
00100000  64 65 66 61 75 6c 74 0a  31 0a 31 0a 31 0a 31 0a  |default.1.1.1.1.|
00100010  32 0a 31 0a 33 0a 30 0a  31 0a 34 0a 32 33 0a 31  |2.1.3.0.1.4.23.1|
00100020  39 0a 31 37 0a 35 0a 32  36 0a 32 34 0a 33 0a 38  |9.17.5.26.24.3.8|
00100030  0a 31 32 0a 31 31 0a 31  30 0a 31 34 0a 31 33 0a  |.12.11.10.14.13.|
00100040  38 32 0a 38 33 0a 38 34  0a                       |82.83.84.|
```

This is a hexdump of arbitrary data.  Assume this data has been loaded into memory at the addresses as shown.  Since the addresses are written in hexadecimal, it is easy to see the bit alignment.

The data at 0x100000 and 0x100001 could be accessed as a 16-bit aligned value (with a suitable CPU instruction or a 16-bit data access through a C pointer reference).  However the data 0x100003 and 0x100004 is not aligned—it spans the 16-bit word at 2 and 3, and the 16-bit word at 4 and 5.  The former is 16-bit aligned and the latter is not.

Likewise, the 64-bit (8 byte) value at 0x100030..100037 is 64-bit aligned.  But everything until 0x100038 is not.

The alignment characteristics are due to the memory bus hardware which organizes memory accesses into bus cycles.  A 16-bit data bus has the ability to fetch 8 bits or 16 bits in one operation, but the latter only if the address is even (least significant address bit is zero).  CPUs which allow "odd alignment" perform two successive bus cycles (one even the other odd) to accomplish the operation.  Other CPUs simply issue faults for non-aligned bus cycles.